# Why can't I contribute subtitles to some YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube, subtitles

[Here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/17471/87002) someone asked if it's possible to contribute subtitles to a YouTube video. I know that it's possible because I contributed Italian subtitles for [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AAdKl1UYZs) (because there is an option to do that).

The following screenshot shows the option:

[image: Contextual menu with option to add subtitles]

Clicking that brings me to [this page](https://www.youtube.com/timedtext_video?v=3AAdKl1UYZs&spfreload=10).

Why can't I find that option on *every* video?

Is it something that uploaders must explicitly enable?

Are there some legal issues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only some channels allow users to contribute subtitles.

From [Contribute subtitles and closed captions - Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6054623?hl=en)

> Some channels let you contribute subtitles and closed captions to
>   their videos. You can submit content for an entire video or just add
>   what you know — every little bit helps make videos more accessible to
>   a larger audience.
>
> If the video's creator accepts your submission, they'll be viewable on
>   the video by clicking on the [CC] icon in the player. Approved content
>   is owned by the video owner, but your YouTube username and public
>   profile may be visible to the video uploader and other video viewers.
>
> **Before you start**: Make sure the video you want to add captions or subtitles to is part of a participating channel.

Comment: I wonder, though, why are there so few participating channels (and how does a channel begin to participate). Maybe there are some legal reasons...

Comment: Besides the legal reasons, I think that could be some technical and operation reasons like the abuse controls.